# How do you represent a text file to be edited in memory in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to create a data structure to describe how a file will be stored, and once that is done I have to implement the methods below into the data structure. I am having trouble figuring what this data structure would be.  What I am doing is that I'm basically creating a primitive Java text editor. Please help with any clarifications and thank you in advance.

`boolean Find (String x) // Looks for a word "x" in the file and returns true if found or false otherwise.`

`boolean FindReplace (String x, String y) // looks for the first occurrence of word "x" in the file and replaces it with word "y" if found returning true, false otherwise.`

`boolean FindInsert (String x, String y)  // looks for the first occurrence of word "x" in the file and then insert "y" right after "x", if x is found, returning true, false otherwise.`

Comment: There are very, very many ways to go about doing this. Is there a more specific problem you're running up against? Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: I've already begun on the implementation methods but I am stuck trying to  come up with the most effective data structure that  will also after a few edits will create a new file

Comment: *will create and save a new file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a class which contains a `StringBuilder`.  You can read an entire disk file into the `StringBuilder`, manipulate it, then save it.

The `StringBuilder` offers an `indexOf(String str)` method that you can use to search for a string, and various `insert`, `delete`, etc operations.

Answer (score 0):

A gap buffer is an efficient way to support these operations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer

Alternatively, you can just use 2 StringBuilders.  Every time you do a Find/Replace or Find/Insert, you transfer the text from one to the other, making changes as you go, and then swap them.